Prove this formula results in an integer for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$
$$\left( \frac{36 + 45 \sqrt{2} i}{22} \left( {1 + 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n + \frac{36 - 45 \sqrt{2} i}{22} \left( {1 - 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n \right) \cdot (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{9} + \frac{4^{n+1}}{11}$$
I have tried using the trigonometric form to get
$$\frac{4}{11} \cdot 3^{2 + n} \cos \left( n \tan^{-1} \left( 2 \sqrt{2} \right) \right) - \frac{5}{11} \sqrt{2} \cdot 3^{2 + n} \sin \left( n \tan^{-1} \left( 2 \sqrt{2} \right) \right)
$$
from inside the big parentheses, and try proving it using induction, but I haven't figured it out yet.
I am stuck, any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you very much

Hint: Try taking the conjugate.

Given the form, show that the terms satisfy a linear recurrence relation with integer coefficients. Then it remains to show that the starting values are integers (which presumably you've done).

thank you guys very much

Let $a_n=\left( \dfrac{36 + 45 \sqrt{2} i}{22} \left( {1 + 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n + \dfrac{36 - 45 \sqrt{2} i}{22} \left( {1 - 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n \right) \cdot (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{9} + \dfrac{4^{n+1}}{11}$.
$(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\dots)=(0,0,12,24,36,480,\dots).$
Let $b_n=  \left( {1 + 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n +   \left( {1 - 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n   +\dfrac54\sqrt2i   \left[\left( {1 + 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n - \left( {1 - 2 \sqrt{2} i} \right)^n \right] $.
$(b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,\dots)=(2,-8,-34,4,314,592,\dots).$
Show by induction that $b_{n+2}=\color{blue}2b_{n+1}-\color{blue}9b_{n}$, so $b_n$ are integers.
($1\pm2\sqrt2i$ are roots of $x^2-\color{blue}2x+\color{blue}9=0$.)
Furthermore, show by induction that $b_{n+1}\equiv-4b_n\bmod11$, so $b_n\equiv2\cdot(-4)^{n}\bmod11$, so
$11a_n={18}b_n\cdot(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\dfrac19+4^{n+1}=2b_n\cdot(-1)^{n+1}+4^{n+1}\equiv4\cdot(-4)^n\cdot(-1)^{n+1}+4^{n+1}$
$\equiv-1\cdot(-4)^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1}+4^{n+1}\equiv-4^{n+1}+4^{n+1}\equiv0\bmod11,$
so $a_n$ are integers.

thank you very much
